# How to make old router as access point?

Tags: router, switch, isp, access-point

I have installed a new router at my home, the new router has 4 ports. And the  ISP only allowed for one port to have internet connection using ethernet. That port is taken by another person, and now only 3 ports left that don't have internet connection.

Is it possible to make my old router as a switch to share the internet connection with that one port that works?

I've tried to connect my old router to any of the 3 ports left, but I cannot access the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put a switch or hub in between. More possibly a switch nowadays.

Comment: you mean a switch in that one port in the new router, and then connecting the the 2 lines to the switch?

Comment: yes, so they share the same MAC address towards the restricted router. Should work.

Comment: A L2 switch works on *data link layer*. Devices behind a switch won't share the same MAC address, so this solution won't work if the connection is restricted to allow only one MAC address. In that case you'd need a router to put the other devices behind a NAT.